# Apache CXF Request Time Out

Tags: java, spring, apache, web-services, cxf

I'm having trouble configuring the request time out for apache CXF web services. Default connection time outs doesn't work.

My requirement is to terminate web service request as soon as client is disconnected and also terminate the request from server end if timeout is exceded.

Currently ws request body contains spring transaction block and when requst is terminating the transaction should also rolled back.

Comment: Your help is really appriciated